# UpperCase the even index of a string

Tags: javascript, string, algorithm

i am trying to UpperCase() the even indexes of a string;

input: hello world;

output: HeLlO  WoRlD;

somehow its not working, i think it is because i cannot mutate a string since it is returning the initial value. Can someone help me solve this problem ?

/* Alternating Caps
Write a function that takes in a string of letters
and returns a sentence in which every other letter is capitalized.

Example input: "I'm so happy it's Monday"
Example output: "I'M So hApPy iT'S MoNdAy"
*/

```
function altCaps(str){
let string = str
for(let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if(i % 2 === 0) {
       string[i].toUpperCase()
    }
}
console.log(string)
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings are immutable, you need to create a new string and append the letters one by one.

```js
function altCaps(oldStr){
  let newStr = '';
  for(let i = 0; i < oldStr.length; i++)
    newStr += i % 2 === 0 ? oldStr[i].toUpperCase() : oldStr[i];
  return newStr;
}
console.log(altCaps("I'm so happy it's monday"))
```

Notice this isn't attempting to mutate `newStr`, it's getting a new string reassigned for every letter we append.

Comment: I appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your solution is that `.toUpperCase()` doesn't modify the string it's called on.  Rather, it returns a new upper-cased string.

Here's one way the problem could be solved:

```js
const test = "Hello World";
const toAltCase = s => s.split("")
                        .map((c, i) => (i % 2 != 0)?
                          c.toLowerCase() : 
                          c.toUpperCase())
                        .join("");

console.log(toAltCase(test), "<-", test);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function altCaps(text,mode=0) {
    return text.split('').map((c,i) => 
        i % 2 == mode ? c.toLowerCase() : c.toUpperCase()
    ).join('');   
}

console.log(altCaps("I'm so happy it's Monday",1));
```

Comment: Cheers, i knew i could change  the initial value of the string,change it to an array and then convert it again is the best option, thank you !